# Как поместить div в нижний правый угол html страницы?

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью css стилей разместить div элемент внизу справа html страницы?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSS**

```
#bottom-right
{
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id=”bottom-right”>Bottom right!</div>
```

Вообще  по андроиду гоню но сейчас что то нашло)))

Answer (score 1):

```css
#bottom-right{
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bottom-right">Текст</div>
```

Из примера выше

Comment: Чужой ответ можно дополнить сниппетом (при достаточном рейтинге), а публиковать чужие ответы как свои нехорошо. Тем более, не очень то он и правильный.

Comment: Извините я все понимаю.. Я в версику вообще на лез никогда. Просто заметил что вопрос прост. Решил нагуглить. Помог человеку :)